# How can I safely call another addon?

Tags: python

How can I check to see if an operator from another addon is installed from my addon? This my current attempt.

```
def doCoolThing():
   try:
           bpy.ops.coolAddon.foo()
    except AttributeError:
           print("COOL ADDON NOT INSTALLED!")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Knowing where the addon should be found is the first thing to sort out. You can either look at the addon source and see where it attaches to, or investigate by hand. Generally you'll find it in the `bl_idname` of the Operator.

For example I have an addon called autoVTX for which the Operator code has these lines at the top:

```
class AutoVTX(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = 'view3d.autovtx'
    bl_label = 'autoVTX'

    # ...
```

This Operator can be accessed from `bpy.ops.view3d.autovtx()`

The `try/except` route is fine btw, as CoDEmanX rightfully points out in the comment. If you know where an addon or operator *should* be when installed then this *should* work.

```
def doCoolThing():
   try:
       bpy.ops.view3d.coolAddon.foo()
   except AttributeError:
       print("COOL ADDON NOT INSTALLED!")
```

Comment: Ben's try/except approach is actually more pythonic: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html?highlight=forgiveness#term-eafp. You could also import another addon's code, but rather if you're interested into a certain function and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to look up the type:

```
if hasattr(bpy.types, "IMPORT_SCENE_OT_obj"): ...
```

You can locate the script like this by the way:

```
>>> sys.modules[bpy.types.IMPORT_SCENE_OT_obj.__module__].__file__
'C:\\Program Files\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.70\\scripts\\addons\\io_scene_obj\\__init__.py'
```

Comment: where does hasattr live?

Comment: it's a built-in language feature, if that's your question